# If BQP is contained in any level of the Polynomial Hierarchy, does it then follow that $NP \subseteq BQP$ implies $PH \subseteq BQP$?

Tags: complexity-theory, np, quantum-computing

I think this is implied in this paper by Aaronson (http://www.scottaaronson.com/papers/bqpph.pdf) but I am not sure.

Begin with $NP \subseteq BQP$ (*)

$\Sigma_{2}^{P} = NP^{NP} \subseteq BQP^{BQP} = BQP$

$\Sigma_{i+1}^{P} = NP^{\Sigma_{i}^{P}} \subseteq BQP^{BQP} = BQP$

With this inductive step we have $PH \subseteq BQP$

The only part of this proof I doubt is the step $NP^{NP} \subseteq BQP^{BQP}$ because I am unsure of some oracle rules.

My assumption is that if $A \subseteq B$ then:

$A^{C}\subseteq B^{C}$

and

$C^{A}\subseteq C^{B}$

with no assumptions about $C$, are these correct?

I feel like this would be a well-known result if it were true without any additional assumptions, so my belief is that I must need to make an additional assumption at some point that I have missed.

Comment: This post belongs to cstheory.stackexchange.com

Comment: Why do you think this is implied in the paper? Can you be more specific?

Comment: Hey Yuval, apologies for not being more specific. If we start at the final paragraph of page 3 (beginning "Fourth) and read until the end of the section. Scott talks through a proof that if $NP \subseteq BQP \subseteq AM$ then the polynomial hierarchy collapses. He then says "similar remarks apply to the question of whether $NP \subseteq BQP$ would imply $PH \subseteq BQP$."

Something like $NP \subseteq BQP$ implies $BQP=BQP^{BQP}\supseteq NP^{NP} = \Sigma_{2}^{P}$ seems intuitive to me but I'm worried I'm making steps that are not allowed.

Comment: If you're not sure something works, try proving it.

Comment: I have added additional details and attempted proof in the main question.

Comment: Notice that $A\subseteq B \Rightarrow A^C\subseteq B^C$ implies $A=B \Rightarrow A^C=B^C$, and check out my old question http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/37626/why-is-this-argument-for-p-neq-np-wrong.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the oracle monotonicity results you mention depend on the exact definition of $X^Y$. But for reasonable $C$ (depending on $A,B$), these results are probably correct. You can try proving them.