# On oracle access containment?

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines, complexity-classes, oracle-machines, oracles

If $X,Y$ are complexity classes in the polynomial hierarchy with $X\subseteq Y$. With abuse of notation assume $X,Y$ also as the TMs that accept languages in classes $X,Y$ respectively.

1. Then is it always true $X^Z\subseteq Y^Z$ if $Z$ is another complexity class?
2. If not what is an easy way and example to understand $X^Z\subseteq Y^Z$ need not be true?

Comment: How do you define $X^Z$ in general? What do you mean by a "complexity class in the polynomial hierarchy"?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus sorry this is what I thought. we are allowed to use $Z$ as a black box polynomially many times if $Z$ has a complete language (if there is no complete language like $BPP$ I am not sure how it is done in example $BPP^{BPP}$). Also by complexity class in the polynomial hierarchy I mean any complexity class in between $L$ and $PSPACE$.

Comment: This is not enough. What are $X,Y$? If you treat them as a set of languages, then it is not clear what "using Z" means, so they need to be defined with regard to some type of bounded resources machine.

Comment: @Ariel actually this is the precise point of the query. Can you please illustrate the nuances?

Comment: Things also depend on what Zs you allow as ​ "another complexity class" . ​ ​ ​ Allowing ​ "problems logspace reducible to S" ​ is at least as general ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ (... continued) ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: (continued ...) ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ as allowing just an oracle for the language S, in which case one can get ​ ​ ​ [TALLY](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:T#tally) $\cap$ co[UP](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:U#up)$^{\hspace{.02 in}Z} \: \not\subseteq \: $ [IP](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:I#ip)$^{\hspace{.02 in}Z} \:$, ​ ​ ​ even though ​ P $\subseteq$ coUP $\subseteq$ PSPACE [=](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_(complexity)#Proof_of_IP_.3D_PSPACE) IP . ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer then under what circumstances can we say $X\subseteq Y\implies X^Z\subseteq Y^Z$?

Comment: @RickyDemer also I do not understand how can $TALLY\subseteq IP$ hold yet still what you say is true.

Comment: Perhaps this question might clear some issues https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/37626/why-is-this-argument-for-p-neq-np-wrong

Comment: @Ariel no because it does not give a $Z$ in polynomial hierarchy such that $P^Z\not\subseteq NP^Z$.

Comment: I didn't say it answers your question, but it shows you why equality (or containment) does not necessarily relativise (i.e. might not hold relative to an oracle). Another example is, if we assume $P=BPP$, the statement $BPP\subseteq P$, since there exists an oracle relative to which $BPP=EXP^{NP}$, which is no longer a subset of $P$.

Comment: @Ariel 1) here we do not assume $X\subseteq Y$ but we know for sure $X\subseteq Y$ and so may be an example with where we know $X\subseteq Y$ for sure would help. 2) I have changed my query for clarity (hope it is correct).

Comment: @Turbo : ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ We can do that when we have proof of ​ X $\subseteq$ Y ​ that necessarily still works after adding an oracle. ​ ​ ​ TALLY is not a subset of IP, since TALLY is countable and IP is countable. ​ (The site's layout may have hidden the intersection sign just after the TALLY in my previous comment.) ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer I do not understand your example $coUP\subseteq IP$ but $coUP^Z\not\subseteq IP^Z$. What oracle are you using for $Z$?